# How can I add and remove classes to buttons that are selected?

Tags: jquery

I have a few buttons that the user can select:

```
<button id="Invitation" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="SetType(1);">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>Invitation</button>
<button id="Assistance" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="SetType(2);">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>Assistance</button>
<button id="Finalize" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" onclick="SetType(3);">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-fw"></i>Finalize</button>
```

They all start out with the same class, but when a user clicks the button I want to add a class.  If they select a different button I want to remove that added class and apply it to the other button.  I have this:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#Invitation,#Assistance,#Finalize").click(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("btn btn-info btn-lg");
        $(this).addClass("btn btn-success btn-lg");
    });
});
```

But it makes all 3 buttons green when I click them.  How can I remove the `btn btn-success btn-lg` from the button when its not the one selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
       $(this).toggleClass("btn-info btn-success");
       $("button").not(this)
          .removeClass("btn-success")
          .addClass("btn-info");
    });
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hdhhjg8a/).

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function ()
 { 
$("#Invitation #Assistance #Finalize").click(function () 
{ 
$(this).removeClass("btn btn-info btn-lg");
 $(this).addClass("btn btn-success btn-lg");
 }); 
});
```